# How to run cosmos db data scripts in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cosmosdb

I want to run few cosmos db scripts as part of my java spring boot deployment process through Azure CD pipeline. I came across this document
[Deploy to Azure Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) but not sure whether its applicable to cosmos db too. Secondly is there any other way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are different services.

You can use code to deploy cosmos db and use devops to run the code.